# ListView (multiple data columns) cannot be displayed

Tags: android

I asked some questions about fixed header and multiple data columns on stackoverflow and I finally came up with something that I think make sense, I feel like I am very close to my goal. Now the problem is that the data didn't get displayed. I did log.i and I found that I did successfully read from my database, So I guess I have some problem with my adapter?

activity:

public class HistoryActivity extends Activity
{

```
private static final String TAG = "HistoryActivity";
ListView lv;
SimpleAdapter sd;

RecordDAO dao = new RecordDAO(HistoryActivity.this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");

    setContentView(R.layout.historyactivityheader);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayList<Record> Records = new ArrayList<Record>();
    Records = (ArrayList<Record>) dao.findAll();


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map;

    for (int x = Records.size()-1; x >=0; x--)
    {
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("ID", String.valueOf(Records.get(x).getId()));
        ...

        aList.add(map);
    }

    sd = new SimpleAdapter(this, aList, R.layout.historyactivityrow,
            new String[]
            { "col1", "col2", "col3",
                    "col4" }, new int[]             
            { R.id.col1, R.id.col2, R.id.col3,
                     R.id.col4});


    lv.setAdapter(sd);




}
```

}

historyactivityheader.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="4dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="col1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="col2"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="col3"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="col4"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

historyactivityrow.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="4dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/col1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/col2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/col3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/col4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

The answer is that the header's height uses fill_parent so it covered the listview...such a stupid mistake...
THerefore, change the following:
the header.xml should be in relativelayout, and place the listview below the headertextview and then also set the listview's width to fill_parent, finally, change header's height to wrap_content